# Hibernate delete item

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-session

When I try to delete an object using HQL, I use hiberate's `session.CreateQuery().executeUpdate()` and it returns 1 item is deleted. However, in database, nothing has been deleted. After `executeUpdate`, I also did flush.

Could anyone give me some suggestion about what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't committed an enclosing transaction. You need something like:

```
tx = session.beginTransaction()
session.createQuery().executeUpdate("...")
tx.commit()
```

Comment: May I ask why I didn't use transaction when I insert new obs into db, but it still works well?Thank you very much:)

Comment: There are a multitude of reasons that vary by database vendor. Ultimately it comes down to this: the database you were using wasn't transactional, one of your connections was at a different isolation level, allowing uncommitted changes to be seen, autocommit was on (everything was committed as it happened), or there *was* a transaction and you just didn't know it.